# How to convert specific colour to HSV/RGB scalar value (Channel 4)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, colors

I am trying to implement colour changing feature for my paint application. Here are some original and expected results.

Original Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTcd0.jpg

Require Output: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIVeS.jpg

Here we have tried multiple approach to achieve this solutions :

1. Render image using "CIFilter"
2. Image color replacement Pixel Wise with tolerance value.
3. Flood fill colours (Not meet with client requirement, Does not fill colour with Alpha Channel)
4. OpenCV.

I am stuck at point where we can find range of particular colour and replace with another one.

We have made a code for replacing colour with another one with OpenCV and objective C after bridging the code in between.

They Grey scale and other method is working properly (e.g. edge detection). But while replacing colour with any HSV and RGB value it returning only Blue value in image. Also the colour is spread in chair and other objects also.

Result as below : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/joqkb.jpg

```
-(UIImage *)ChangeColor:(UIImage *)processedImage col:(UIColor *)color { 
    UIColor *color1 = [self lighterColorForColor:color];
    UIColor *color2 = [self darkerColorForColor:color];
    UIColor *color3 = [self setColor:[arrForColor objectAtIndex:selectedColor] alpha:1.0];
   [color1 getRed:&r1 green:&g1 blue:&b1 alpha:&a1];
   [color2 getRed:&r2 green:&g2 blue:&b2 alpha:&a2];
   [color3 getRed:&r3 green:&g3 blue:&b3 alpha:&a3];

    CGFloat r1, g1, b1, a1, r2, g2, b2, a2, r3, g3, b3, a3;
    [color1 getHue:&r1 saturation:&g1 brightness:&b1 alpha:nil];
    [color2 getHue:&r2 saturation:&g2 brightness:&b2 alpha:nil];
    [color3 getHue:&r3 saturation:&g3 brightness:&b3 alpha:nil];

    r1 = r1 * 255;
    r2 = r2 * 255;
    r3 = r3 * 255;

    g1 = g1 * 255;
    g2 = g2 * 255;
    g2 = g3 * 255;

    b1 = b1 * 255;
    b2 = b2 * 255;
    b3 = b3 * 255;

    cv::Mat img=[MMOpenCVHelper cvMatFromUIImage:processedImage];
    cv::Mat hsvImage = cv::cvarrToMat(cvCreateImage(img.size(),8, 3));
    cv::cvtColor(img, hsvImage, CV_BGR2HSV);

    std::vector<cv::Mat>channels;

    cv::split(hsvImage, channels);
    cv::Mat hue = channels[0];
    cv::Mat dest;
    cv::Mat temp= cv::cvarrToMat(cvCreateImage(img.size(), 8, 3));

    cv::inRange(hsvImage, cv::Scalar(10,10,10), cv::Scalar(20,20,20), dest);
    cv::merge(channels, temp);
    temp.setTo(cv::Scalar(50,50,50),dest);
    cv::split(temp, channels);
    cv::merge(channels, dest);
    cv::cvtColor(dest, hsvImage, CV_HSV2RGB);

    UIImage *grayeditImage=[MMOpenCVHelper UIImageFromCVMat:hsvImage];

    return grayeditImage;
}

- (UIColor *)lighterColorForColor:(UIColor *)c
{
    CGFloat r, g, b, a;
    if ([c getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a])
        return [UIColor colorWithRed:MIN(r + 0.1, 1.0)
                               green:MIN(g + 0.1, 1.0)
                                blue:MIN(b + 0.1, 1.0)
                               alpha:a];
    return nil;
}

- (UIColor *)darkerColorForColor:(UIColor *)c
{
    CGFloat r, g, b, a;
    if ([c getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a])
        return [UIColor colorWithRed:MAX(r - 0.1, 0.0)
                               green:MAX(g - 0.1, 0.0)
                                blue:MAX(b - 0.1, 0.0)
                               alpha:a];
    return nil;
}
```

Why is it returning only blue color even if I am setting different Scalar value?

Comment: Hey have you found any solution.?

Comment: yes, Not fully but some of the portion is still pending. We are working on it.